# Replace Fragment on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I want to replace my current Fragment by a new one when I click on `FloatingActionButton`. I tried it with a fragmentReplace but my app keeps crashing.

Am i missing something?

**Code:**

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            android.app.Fragment someFrag = new NewEventActivity();
            replaceFragment(someFrag);

            //Snackbar.make(view, "Hallo du heimlich pupsende :P", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
             //       .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }

    });

}


public void replaceFragment(android.app.Fragment someFrag){
    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.newEvent, someFrag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class NewEventActivity extends android.app.Fragment {

LayoutInflater inflater;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_event_fragment, container, false);


    return rootView;
   }
 }
```

**Logcat**

> Process: com.example.danny.myapplication, PID: 3123
>                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0082
>   (com.example.danny.myapplication:id/newEvent) for fragment
>   NewEventActivity{bd7d3d #2 id=0x7f0c0082}
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: please add your logcat

Comment: are you trying to replace the current fragment with a new one?

Comment: android.support.v4.app.Fragment use it instead of android.app.Fragment.

Comment: @Bansal It is not necessary

Comment: Logs please ...

Comment: have you given newEvent id in your activity class?

Comment: logcat added...

Comment: which layout is set in setContentView() method in NewEventActivity

Comment: please add your xml code

Comment: put your Activity and its layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view **R.id.newEvent** should be the child layout of what you have defined in setContentView() method in your activity.

Comment: where? or how??

Comment: whatever layout you set in onCreateView() method,that layout should contain that view that has an id newEvent

Comment: so that means that the fragmant which should replace the actual fragment needs to be in the same xml?:O

Comment: No i am saying that the id R.id.newEvent needs to in the layout which is added in setContentView(R.layout.yourXml) method in activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_activity,
new YourNewFragment()).addToBackStack(YourPreviousFragment.class.getName())
.commit();
```